# How to pass data member as default argument to class method?

Tags: c++

I am creating a recursive function to reverse a linked list.

```cpp
class LinkedList {

    node *head;

  public:
    node *reverse(/* Here, I want to pass the head as a default argument */);
}
```

I have tried to do `node *reverse(node *nd = this->head)` but it raises the following error:

> 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function

Why is this happening? How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: use an overload instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the default argument is supposed to be provided from the caller context, where `this` doesn't exist.

You can provide an overload.

```
class LinkedList {

    node *head;

  public:
    node *reverse(...);
    node *reverse() { return reverse(this->head); }
};
```

Comment: So if i got this right, it would have worked if the default argument was `static`, right?

Comment: @PriyanshulGovil Yes. Then you can declare it like `node *reverse(node *nd = LinkedList::head);`.

Comment: perfect. that makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

You might create overloads:

```
class LinkedList {
    node *head;
public:
    node *reverse(node*);
    node *reverse() { return reverse(head); }
    // ...
};
```